# Como colocar dados de db em mais de um fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite

Eu quero colocar os dados do banco em fragments, em um swipe, não uma lista, onde cada registro seja carregado em um fragment diferente.

Comment: Então. Cada fragment exibiria uma pessoa cadastrada no banco, e neste mesmo fragment teria um pequeno formulário para responde-la. Eu consegui um exemplo em um livro que apresenta os fragments em lista, mas eu precisaria que fosse um swipe. Ficou mais claro?

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria entender melhor seu objetivo final, mas você poderia conseguir este efeito criando um [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) com um **LinearLayout horizontal**. Fazendo apenas uma consulta ao banco e alimentando o RecyclerView com o cursor. O RecyclerView é bem eficaz e econômico.

Outra possibilidade seria utilizar [Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html)

Como falei, depende muito do seu objetivo. Acho que você poderia estudar um pouco estas opções.